# Join Custom lists in java

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

I have two custom lists as follows.

```
List<OfficeName> = [{id: 1, offname: "Office1"}{id: 2, offname: "Office2"}]
List<OfficeLocation> = [{id: 1, offlocation: "location1"}{id: 2, offlocation: "locatio2"}]
```

I want result as follows:

```
list<OfficeDetails> =  [{id: 1, offname: "Office1",offlocation: "location1" },
                        {id: 2, offname: "Office2", offlocation: "location2"}]
```

The first two lists needs to be joined on basis of "id" to give a new list which is equivalent to the join operation in sql tables.

My model classes are

```
public class OfficeName {
int id;
String  offname;
//getter and setter
}
```

.................

```
public class OfficeLocation{
int id;
String  offlocation;
//getter and setter
}
```

.........

Currently I am Iterating and manually adding as follows to a LinkedHashSet .

```
{
List<OfficeName> officeName =  new ArrayList<OfficeName>();
    onr.findById(id).forEach(officeName::add); // adding values from auto wired Repository
    
    
    List<OfficeLocation> officeLocation =  new ArrayList<OfficeLocation>();
    olr.findById(id).forEach(officeLocation::add); // adding values from auto wired Repository

  LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> lhs   = new LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String> >();
     OfficeName officeName1 =  new OfficeName();
     OfficeLocation officeLocation1 =  new OfficeLocation();
    
    Iterator<OfficeName> onIterator = officeName.iterator();
    Iterator<OfficeLocation> olIterator = officeLocation.iterator();
    
    while (onIterator.hasNext()) {
        officeName1 =onIterator.next();
        int idon =officeName1.getId();

        while(olIterator.hasNext()){
            officeLocation1 = olIterator.next();
            int idol = officeLocation1.getId();
        
            if(idon==idol)
            {               

                 lhs.add(new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList( String.valueOf(officeName1.getId()),officeName1.getOffname(),officeLocation1.getOfflocation())));
                 olIterator.remove();
                 break;
            }
        }; 
    }
```

---

I am not sure whether this is correct way to achieve the same as I am new to java. In C#, this could able to achieve through data tables. Please suggest whether there is any faster way?

Comment: Are the objects distinct in both lists, no duplicates of office id in either?

Comment: this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230629/merging-objects-from-two-list-with-unique-id-using-java-8

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both input lists:

- Are distinct, with no duplicate `id` values in either, and…
- Are complete, with a single object in both lists for each possible `id` value

… then we can get the work done with little code.

I use `NavigableSet` or `SortedSet` implementations to hold our input lists, the names and the locations. Though I have not verified, I assume being sorted will yield better performance when searching for a match across input collections.

To get the sorting done, we define a `Comparator` for each input collection: `Comparator.comparingInt( OfficeName :: id )` & `Comparator.comparingInt( OfficeLocation :: id )` where the double-colons make a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). To each `NavigableSet` we add the contents of our inputs, an unmodifiable list made with the convenient literals syntax of [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E)).

To get the actual work done of joining these two input collections, we make a stream of either input collection. Then we produce a new object of our third joined class using inputs from each element of the stream plus its counterpart found via a stream of the other input collection. These newly produced objects of the third joined class are then collected into a list.

```java
NavigableSet < OfficeName > officeNames = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparingInt( OfficeName :: id ) );
officeNames.addAll( List.of( new OfficeName( 1 , "Office1" ) , new OfficeName( 2 , "Office2" ) ) );

NavigableSet < OfficeLocation > officeLocations = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparingInt( OfficeLocation :: id ) );
officeLocations.addAll( List.of( new OfficeLocation( 1 , "location1" ) , new OfficeLocation( 2 , "locatio2" ) ) );

List < Office > offices = officeNames.stream().map( officeName -> new Office( officeName.id() , officeName.name() , officeLocations.stream().filter( officeLocation -> officeLocation.id() == officeName.id() ).findAny().get().location() ) ).toList();
```

Results:

> officeNames = [OfficeName[id=1, name=Office1], OfficeName[id=2, name=Office2]]
>
> officeLocations = [OfficeLocation[id=1, location=location1], OfficeLocation[id=2, location=locatio2]]
>
> offices = [Office[id=1, name=Office1, location=location1], Office[id=2, name=Office2, location=locatio2]]

Our three classes, the two inputs and the third joined one, are all written as [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) here for their convenient brevity. This Java 16+ feature is a brief way to declare a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Note that a record can be defined locally as well as nested or separate.

```java
public record OfficeName( int id , String name ) { }

public record OfficeLocation( int id , String location ) { }

public record Office( int id , String name , String location ) { }
```

Given the conditions outlined above, we could optimize by hand-writing loops to manage the matching of objects across the input collections, rather than using streams. But I would not be concerned about the performance impact unless you had huge amounts of data that had proven to be a bottleneck. Otherwise, using streams makes for less code and more fun.

Answer (score 0):

One of the lists (e.g. `locations`) should be converted into a map (HashMap) by a key on which the joining should be made, in this case `id` field.

Then, assuming that `OfficeDetails` class has an all-args constructor, the resulting list may be retrieved by streaming the other list `offices` and mapping its contents into new `OfficeDetails`, filling the remaining `location` argument by looking up the map.

```java
List<OfficeName> offices = Arrays.asList(
    new OfficeName(1, "Office1"), new OfficeName(2, "Office2"), new OfficeName(3, "Office3")
);
List<OfficeLocation> locations = Arrays.asList(
    new OfficeLocation(1, "Location 1"), new OfficeLocation(2, "Location 2"), new OfficeLocation(4, "Location 4")
);

Map<Integer, OfficeLocation> mapLoc = locations
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            OfficeLocation::getId,
            loc -> loc,
            (loc1, loc2) -> loc1 // to resolve possible duplicates
        ));
        
List<OfficeDetails> details = offices
        .stream()
        .filter(off -> mapLoc.containsKey(off.getId())) // inner join
        .map(off -> new OfficeDetails(
            off.getId(), off.getOffname(),
            mapLoc.get(off.getId()).getOfflocation() // look up the map
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
details.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (assuming `toString` is implemented in `OfficeDetails`):

```
{id: 1, offname: "Office1", offlocation: "Location 1"}
{id: 2, offname: "Office2", offlocation: "Location 2"}
```

---

If `offices` list is not filtered by condition `mapLoc.containsKey`, an implementation of LEFT JOIN is possible (when `null` locations are stored in the resulting `OfficeDetails`).

To implement RIGHT JOIN (with `null` office names and all available locations), a lookup map should be created for `offices`, and main iteration has to be run for `locations` list.

To implement FULL JOIN (where either name or location parts of `OfficeDetails` can be `null`), two maps need to be created and then joined:

```java
Map<Integer, OfficeName> mapOff = offices
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            OfficeName::getId,
            off -> off,
            (off1, off2) -> off1, // to resolve possible duplicates
            LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
        
List<OfficeDetails> fullDetails = Stream.concat(mapOff.keySet().stream(), mapLoc.keySet().stream())
        .distinct()
        .map(id -> new OfficeDetails(
            id, 
            Optional.ofNullable(mapOff.get(id)).map(OfficeName::getOffname).orElseGet(()->null), 
            Optional.ofNullable(mapLoc.get(id)).map(OfficeLocation::getOfflocation).orElseGet(()->null) 
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
fullDetails.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
{id: 1, offname: "Office1", offlocation: "Location 1"}
{id: 2, offname: "Office2", offlocation: "Location 2"}
{id: 3, offname: "Office3", offlocation: null}
{id: 4, offname: null, offlocation: "Location 4"}
```